# getting the prime numbers scanner

Tags: java

I am using the below code and it's giving me the option to enter the final value but I need to give input of two values and also the total count of prime numbers between that range.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers: ");
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop through the numbers one by one
    for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
        boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

        // check to see if the number is prime
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrimeNumber = false;
                break; // exit the inner for loop
            }
        }

        // print the number if prime
        if (isPrimeNumber) {
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + primes.size());

    System.out.println(primes.toString());
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The code you posted does exactly what you say. It takes the input, finds the prime numbers between 0 and the input and prints out the number of prime numbers as well and all the prime numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your but fine but not exactly as you've described.

**scanner.nextInt()** - can produce only one int value (or causes InputMismatchException if input isn't an int).

You said *'i need to give input of two values'* - to accomplish it you may have to read these values separately using *nextInt()* or you can read both as a line, then split the line, and parse to int separately.
The first option is definitely easier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers: ");
    System.out.print("start = ");
    int start = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("end = ");
    int end = scanner.nextInt();

    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop through the numbers from start to end inclusive
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        // check if i is prime
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + primes.size());
    System.out.println(primes);
}

private static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    // check to see if the number is prime
    for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break; // exit the inner for loop
        }
    }
    return i != 1 && isPrime;
}
```

Let us know, please, is that what you wanted to achieve?

---

**MORE PERFORMANT IMPLEMENTATION**

In this implementation, all functionality for finding primes resides in the separate class **PrimeUtil**.

The constructor of this class is private and to create an instance of this class, it provides a static method **getInstance()** which accepts two integer numbers representing the desired range.

This is done in order to initialize the object by invoking the **init()** method and return a fully-fledged object primeUtil, containing the result to the caller.

Method **init()** populates **primes** list. All discovered prime numbers will be added to it.

**primes** list acts as cash. There's no need to rediscover primes over and over again like it's dome in the first solution. That drastically improves the performance.

Another optimization is the way to determine the next probable prime implemented in the method **getNextCandidate()**.

The mathematical logic behind this method is based on the fact that all numbers, that are evenly divisible by 2 and 3 are already eliminated because 2 and 3, are added to the **primes** list by default and there is no need to consider any number that is divisible **2** or **3**. From this fact we can make a conclusion that the remainder of division by **6** for every potential prime *cant be equal: 0; 2; 3; 4*. I.e. valid prime must fulfill the condition **prime % 6 == 1 || prime % 6 == 5**.

- **main**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPrimes();
    }

    public static void printPrimes() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers: ");
        System.out.print("start = ");
        int start = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("end = ");
        int end = scanner.nextInt();

        List<Integer> primes = PrimeUtil.getInstance(start, end).getResult();

        System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + primes.size());
        System.out.println(primes);
    }
```

- **PrimeUtil class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Math.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toUnmodifiableList;

public class PrimeUtil {
    private final List<Integer> primes;
    private final int loBound;
    private final int hiBound;

    private PrimeUtil(int loBound, int hiBound) {
        this.primes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.loBound = loBound;
        this.hiBound = hiBound;
    }

    public static PrimeUtil getInstance(int loBound, int hiBound) {
        PrimeUtil primeUtil = new PrimeUtil(max(loBound, 2), hiBound);
        primeUtil.init();
        return primeUtil;
    }

    private void init() {
        if (loBound <= 2) primes.add(2);
        if (loBound <= 3) primes.add(3);

        int candidate = 5;
        while (candidate <= hiBound) {
            if (isPrime(candidate)) {
                primes.add(candidate);
            }
            candidate = getNextCandidate(candidate);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPrime(int candidate) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.size() && primes.get(i) <= sqrt(candidate); i++) {
            if (candidate % primes.get(i) == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }

    private int getNextCandidate(int candidate) {
        return candidate % 6 == 5 ? candidate + 2 : candidate + 4;
    }

    public List<Integer> getResult() {
        return primes.stream()
                .dropWhile(i -> i < loBound)
                .collect(toUnmodifiableList());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alexander Ivanchenko the code is printing prime numbers as below where 1 and 4 should not be prime numbers.

Please enter two positive integers: 
1 100
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

Comment: @javabeginner there was a typo in the condition of isPrime

Comment: @javabeginner please try it again

Comment: @javabeginner  I just finished with a more performant solution for this task, I'm gonna add to my comment and I'll be glad if you check it

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to ask the user for two integer numbers using `Scanner` two times.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers:");

    System.out.print("low range: ");
    int lo = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("high range: ");
    int hi = scan.nextInt();
    List<Integer> primes = getPrimeNumbers(lo, hi);

    System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + primes.size());
    System.out.println(primes);
}

private static List<Integer> getPrimeNumbers(int lo, int hi) {
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++)
        if (isPrime(i))
            primes.add(i);

    return primes;
}

private static boolean isPrime(int val) {
    if (val == 1)
        return false;
    if (val == 2 || val == 3)
        return true;

    for (int i = 2, sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(val); i <= sqrt; i++)
        if (val % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: add the following condition: `if (candidate % 2 == 0 || candidate % 3 == 0) return false;`

Comment: change the loop: `for (int i = 6; i <= Math.sqrt(candidate); i += 6)`

Comment: `if (candidate % (i - 1) == 0 || candidate % (i + 1) == 0) return false;`

Comment: it'll reduce number of iterations inside isPrime() by 66 %

Comment: You can find a detailed explanation in my answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

1. use two Scanners to get second input
2. you can remove the list and adding elements to it and use a counter if you want only the number of prime numbers :)

So the solution would be :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the first positive integer: ");
    int firstNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the second positive integer: ");


// you should have another scanner hence an other text output to invite user
    int secondNumber = scanner.nextInt();

    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(); // we do not really need this if we want only the number of prime number and not the list but i'll use it for you anyway

    for(int i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++) //the use the input variables
    {
        if (isPrime(i)){ // we made a function here to make things clear. it's role to tell weather a number is a prime or not
            primes.add(i); // we add prime numbers to this list as you used a  list. You can go for an easier solution just a counter++ each time ;)
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The number of prime numbers in this range is: " + primes.size());

}
static boolean isPrime(int num){
    if (num <= 1)
        return false;
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++)
        // If a divisor of n exists
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```